# Access object into array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to access the key 'category', 'specCategory' and 'total' The key and value I want to save it into array for Angular2 ***ngFor**

How can I do this?

```
 let data =   [ { _id: { category: 'Wasser & Wind', specCategory: 'Surfen' },
  min: 49, max: 500, total: 1 }, { _id: { category: 'Reisen', specCategory: 
'Hotel' }, min: 49, max: 500, total: 1 } ]
```

**1) *ngFor**:

I tried to access via `*ngFor="let x of data" {{x._id.category}}` but this is not working

**2)** `JSON.parser` and `JSON.stringify`:

Also I used `JSON.parser` and `JSON.stringify` like that

```
let dataJson = JSON.stringyfy(data[0]._id);
console.log(dataJson.category);
```

Getting error.

**3) For loop:**

I tried with the `for` loop like that

```
for(var i in data){
    console.log(data[i].category)
}
```

> Error: Can not find category

Comment: You mean into array of objects like [`{ category: 'Wasser & Wind', specCategory: 'Surfen' , total: 1}`] ?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please clarify what expected results are and show what you have tried

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Make an attempt and people can guide you the right way.

Comment: See my edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I can guess from your question, you want something like:

```
const data = [{
    _id: {category: 'Wasser & Wind', specCategory: 'Surfen'},
    min: 49,
    max: 500,
    total: 1
}, {_id: {category: 'Reisen', specCategory: 'Hotel'},
    min: 49,
    max: 500,
    total: 1
}];       
const result = data.map(item => ({'category': item._id.category, 'specCategory': item._id.specCategory, 'total': item.total}));
```

And then in HTML (for example):

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of result">{{item.category}}: {{item.specCategory}} ({{item.total}})</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But of course you might want to be more defensive against availability of cascaded keys, so to avoid bad data crashing your app/component if something is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try `of` instead of `in` in your `for` loop, like this:

```
for (d of data) {
   alert(d._id.category)
}
```

The `of` will iterate through the objects themselves, where `in` will iterate through the `keys` of the object.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/536e9b24/) for an example.